# How to create a Nodejs MySQL execute query for values that might not exist

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm inserting values into a MySQL database using Nodejs mysql2 library.

Here is an example of a prepared statement:

```
await conn.execute(
    'INSERT INTO Friends (id, user, name, gender) VALUES (UUID(), ?, ?, ?)',
    [ user, body.name, body.gender ]
);
```

How can I achieve the above if sometimes the `body.gender` value is not set? I want several attributes in the http request to be optional and insert all allowed values that have been sent in the http request into the database.

The above code gives an error if I leave `body.gender` out of the http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no some data in body or not sending some data from the client to register in the database, you have to put a `null` value for that row in that column. You can use this JavaScript feature to do this:

```
await conn.execute(
    'INSERT INTO Friends (id, user, name, gender) VALUES (UUID(), ?, ?, ?)',
    [ user || null, body.name || null, body.gender || null ]
);
```

Using this possibility, in the absence of any of the data sent in the body, its value is `undefined` and the value of `null` is placed in the query.